# How to tell the Rust compiler that a borrow has ended?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

While [checking out tutorials](https://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2015/07/08/understanding-lifetime-in-rust-part-ii-3/) about Rust, I came across a problem with the borrow checker. The following code doesn't compile:

```
struct Car {
    model: String,
}

struct Person<'a> {
    car: Option<&'a Car>,
}

impl<'a> Person<'a> {
    fn new() -> Person<'a> {
        Person { car: None }
    }

    fn buy_car(&mut self, c: &'a Car) {
        // how to say that Person don't borrow the old car any longer?
        self.car = Some(c);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let civic = Car { model: "Honda Civic".to_string() };
    let mut ghibli = Car { model: "Maserati Ghibli".to_string() };
    let mut bob = Person::new();

    bob.buy_car(&ghibli);

    bob.buy_car(&civic);

    // error: cannot borrow `ghibli` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
    let anything = &mut ghibli;
}
```

I understand that because of it's lexical nature Rust's borrow checker can't recognize that the borrow of `ghibli` has already ended.

But I would really like to know how to solve this problem the Rust way? Do I have to use `Rc<T>` or `Box<T>` in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case where the static borrow rules don't work, since there's dynamic behaviour going on that you can't tell the compiler about.

You need to use `Rc<T>`, which can do the borrowing checks at runtime; or if you need mutable access then `Rc<Cell<T>>` or `Rc<RefCell<T>>`.  Then as long as you access it in a dynamically safe way, all will be well.

Answer (score 4):

The "Rust way" to tell the borrow-checker that a borrow ended is to introduce a new scope:

```
fn main() {
    let civic = Car{model: "Honda Civic".to_string()};
    let mut ghibli = Car{model: "Maserati Ghibli".to_string()};
    {
        let mut bob = Person::new();

        bob.buy_car(&ghibli);

        bob.buy_car(&civic);
    }
    let anything = &mut ghibli;
}
```

What you have to realize though, is that in your example, (and probably in most cases anyway) the borrow-checker was right.

`Bob` borrowed a reference to `ghibli`. It is still present at the end of the main method in his `car` field.

Comment: No: `bob.buy_car(&civic)` overwrites the `car` field. So the borrow checker is "wrong"... although I think it's right for it to be so simple.

Comment: Ah. Yes of course, you are right. Must have overlooked that.

Comment: @MatthieuM. My understanding is that borrow checker does not look inside methods, it only sees the declarations. Think about using a method from compiled library, with no source code available, for example.

Comment: @hamstergene: your understanding is more or less correct. The borrow checker peeks inside `enum`/`struct` (to infer whether they borrow/own) does not peek inside functions and only use their signature. There are two benefits to this simplicity: a well-defined boundary (you can change the internals of a function without breaking the analysis) and a relative simplicity of implementation (simulating all the code paths of a function would be... hellish?). Still, we could imagine some supplementary syntax to indicate replacement semantics and such... I don't think it's worth it (too rare a case).